# Программа для отзеркаливания слов в строке, если программе дать строку с 2 пробелами между словами она выдает строку с 1 пробелом

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

```
def reverse_words(text):
    text = text[::-1]
    text_lst = text.split()
    text_lst.reverse()
    b = " ".join(text_lst)
    return b
```

Comment: Что нужно изменить или добавить чтоб программа сохраняла количество пробелов в строке?

Comment: приведите примеры строк

Comment: Намудрили Вы конечно с использованием массивов. Есть способ намного проще, его уже описали в ответе ниже.

Comment: если просто подправить Ваш код, то заменить `.split()` на `.split(" ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для переворачивания строки достаточно :

```
def reverse_words(text):
    return text[::-1]

print(reverse_words('кoт  собака  кот   собака'))
```

В вашем примере вы переворачиваете строку, разбиваете эту строку на элементы массива, тем самым все пробелы исходной строки удаляются, а с помощью join вы добавляете только по одному пробелу.

Comment: Ввод: **кoт  собака  кот   собака**
Вывод: **тoк акабос ток акабос**
но с сохранение количества пробелов

Comment: я видимо ошибся в описании мне нужно отзеркалить каждое слово из строки, а саму строку оставить в том же порядке.

Comment: на данный вопрос ответил Andrey Maslov в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Дело было вечером, делать было нечего. И так, "фантазия на тему":

```py
import re
from itertools import zip_longest

line = 'Программа для  отзеркаливания   слов и строк'


def words_flip(text: str, flip_words: bool = False, flip_line: bool = False):
    spaces = re.findall(r'\s+', text)
    words = re.findall(r'\S+', text)

    if flip_line:
        spaces.reverse()
        words.reverse()

    new_line_list = [
        (word[::-1] if flip_words else word) + (space if space else '') for word, space in zip_longest(words, spaces)
    ]

    new_line = ''.join(new_line_list)

    print(new_line)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    words_flip(line, flip_words=True, flip_line=True)
```

Comment: Извините я не правильно описал свой вопрос, теперь все верно исправлено, суть программы в том чтоб перевернуть каждое слово из строки не меняя порядка слов в ней.

Comment: @Deathstroke, вышенаписанный код делает как Вам будет удобно, нужно только параметры функции поменять. К примеру так `words_flip(line, flip_words=True)`

Comment: @Deathstroke. Да без проблем )))). Не понятно только чем. это абсолютно тождественные выражения как мне кажется